# How do I make a variable in scala change?

Tags: scala, variables, scope

So I have this variable, currentPartNumber, which starts off being equal to 0.  What I want to happen is in my function, if the variable is equal to zero, it is changed to 1 and the text is printed out.  Same thing for my second function - if the variable was changed to 1 in my first function and is equal to one, I want the variable to change to 2 an print out the text.

The problem is: How do I get the variable to change with each function call like I want?

```
var currentPartNumber = 0

def roomOne():Unit = {
   if (currentPartNumber < 1) {
      var currentPartNumber = 1
      println("You now have parts 1 of 4.")
     } else {
      println("This part cannot be collected yet.")
   {
   }


def roomTwo():Unit = {
   if (currentPartNumber = 1) {
      var currentPartNumber = 2
      println("You now have parts 2 of 4.")
     } else {
      println("This part cannot be collected yet.")
   {
   }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't shadow the variable: remove the `var` from inside the functions.

The `var` keyword *declares* a *new* member/variable. In this case the name is the same which *shadows* the variable from the outer scope. Thus the assignment (as part of the declaration) has no affect on the outer variable.

```
// no var/val - assignment without declaration
currentPartNumber = 2
```

See also:

- [Why does a scala try block allow variables from the enclosing scope to be redefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14979813/why-does-a-scala-try-block-allow-variables-from-the-enclosing-scope-to-be-redefi)
- [Why does Scala support shadow variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031106/why-does-scala-support-shadow-variables)

Answer (score 1):

Declare `currentPartNumber` in a class where `roomOne()` and `roomTwo()` can access and modify it.

```
class Parts{
  var currentPartNumber = 0

  def roomOne():Unit = {
    if (currentPartNumber < 1) {
      currentPartNumber = 1
      println("You now have parts 1 of 4.")
    } else {
      println("This part cannot be collected yet.")
    } 
  }  

  def roomTwo():Unit = {
    if (currentPartNumber == 1) {
       currentPartNumber = 2
       println("You now have parts 2 of 4.")
     } else {
      println("This part cannot be collected yet.")
     }
   }
}



scala> :load Parts.scala
Loading Parts.scala...
defined class Parts
scala> var parts = new Parts
parts: Parts = Parts@5636a67c
scala> parts.currentPartNumber
res0: Int = 0
scala> parts.roomOne
You now have parts 1 of 4.
scala> parts.roomTwo
You now have parts 2 of 4.
```

Comment: This works, but my situation is very simple so the other answer works just fine.  Thanks though!